# Syntax Error Trying To Run A Bundle Install GEMFILES for Heroku's server in One Month Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gemfile

I'm doing [one month rails](https://onemonthrails.com/). I keep running into some issues with syntax. I'm trying to run `bundle install`. I've tried with and without the `production` command with the same error.

Error/

> Gemfile syntax error on line 13: syntax error, unexpected tSYMBEG,
>   expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('

syntax /

```
group :development, :test do
     gem 'sqlite3' end 

group :production do
     gem 'pg'
     gem 'rails_12factor' end

   ^


source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.1.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          

group :development, :test do
     gem 'sqlite3'
end 

group :production do
     gem 'pg'
     gem 'rails_12factor'
end

group :doc do

# Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background.         Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
gem 'spring',       require:false
end
```

full error>Gemfile syntax error on line 13: syntax error, unexpected tSYMBEG, expecting
keyword_do or '{' or '('
group :development, :test do

The carrot is pointint to the d in development
       ^

Comment: show us your Gemfile.

Comment: source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.1.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          

group :development, :test do
     gem 'sqlite3'
end 

group :production do
     gem 'pg'
     gem 'rails_12factor'
end

group :doc do

# Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
gem 'spring',       require:false
end

Comment: let  me know if you need something different...  Teacher moonlighting in programming trying to create an ed app for class... sorry if I am not responding correctly.. first project.

Comment: please put that in the question body, and with a proper format! Follow this convention for syntax: http://bundler.io/v1.3/gemfile.html

Comment: group :development, :test do
       ^

Comment: is there any chance you are on ruby `1.8` ?

Comment: using sublime text 2.... file gemfile... obviously

Comment: Gemfile syntax error on line 25: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting
keyword_end
gem 'sdoc,'        group: :development
                        ^
    on line 38: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting     keyword_end

Answer (score 2):

The error is in the `sdoc` line, you have a trailing comma there

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',
```

should be

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0'
```

do so and your bundle will be installed.

Syntax error messages can be tricky.